# OSGi Karaf Scala UnsupportedAudioFileException

Tags: scala, maven, audio, osgi, karaf

this is my first post here. I'm currently working on a simple http audio servlet in Scala on Apache-Karaf 3.0.0. I'm deploying it as a feature from inside some bundles, which I've built using a maven project. I'm using the 'javax.sound.sampled' library to get the audio, and I'm loading the file from the AudioSystem with 'java.io.File'.

```
    val file = new File("audioFile.wav")
    val audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)
```

This is obviously not the actual code, as I've stripped out all of the trivial bits. But this is where it fails, on the 'getAudioInputStream' call.

When I deploy this code to Karaf it fails with 'UnsupportedAudioFileException'. The file does exist, and is readable, I've already validated this. Also, I've made sure that this code can be run under the following.
  - Scala 2.10.2, 2.10.3
  - Java 1.7.0_45  ( This is the same JRE as my Karaf program is using )
  - SBT 0.12.4 ( With the different Scala versions )

The only place this fails is when I deploy it to Karaf. I don't know if Karaf has cut out some random audio support, or what is going on, because this otherwise works when deployed through SBT or using the Scala command line. I've also looked into alternative libraries, but to no avail. Most other solutions seem to be based around actually playing the audio through a sound driver, which is useless to me. I need the actual byte data.

Also, keep in mind that just sending the file over is also useless me. Another requirement is that I need to be able to be able to merge multiple audio files in to one seamless audio stream. I already have this done, I just need to port it to OSGi, and for some reason I am now getting this error. I don't know if Karaf has something to do with it, or if my building it through a Maven project has broken something. I've looked around, and have found very little hint as to where the problem might be.

The audio files I'm using are of Waveform audio. 8,000 sampling rate, 16 bits per sample. I don't think this would actually make a difference, but I'm no expert on audio formats.

My pom.xml dependencies are as follows. The only plugin I'm using is the Scala compiler, and of course my root pom.xml is using the org.apache.felix maven-bundle-plugin. There's really not much magic going on here, yet the mystery remains.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any clues would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think AudioSystem is not fully OSGi ready. This is what I found in the Aries Spy Fly dcoumentation.
Not sure what exactly you have to do to make it work but this might help.

https://aries.apache.org/modules/spi-fly.html

Special Cases

SPI Fly can be used for most SPI provider/lookup systems that use the TCCL pattern to obtain implementations. However in some cases, some special treatment is needed. This special treatment is often needed when the API itself does not match the name of the resources in META-INF/services, java.util.ServiceLoader is such a case, however SPI-Fly has built-in knowledge of ServiceLoader. Known APIs that require special treatment are listed below:

javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem: This class uses sun.misc.Service under the covers (via com.sun.media.sound.JDK13Services) which is a predecessor to java.util.ServiceLoader. There is no special treatment for sun.misc.Service in SPI Fly (yet), but the AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream() API can be made to work by explicitly listing it in the provider bundle (the one that contains the relevant META-INF/services resources): SPI-Provider: javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem on the consumer side you can use SPI-Consumer: javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem#getAudioInputStream

Comment: Ah! I will definitely take a look into that. Thank you very much. All of this is still very new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Christian's answer is correct but I wanted to provide an updated link to the [spifly](http://aries.apache.org/modules/spi-fly.html) documentation page. Specifically:

> Java's java.util.ServiceLoader.load(), other similar methods such as
>   sun.misc.Service.providers() and also other static finder methods such
>   as the FactoryFinder.find() methods try to locate 'service'
>   implementations by looking for resources in the META-INF/services
>   directory of all the jars visible to the Thread Context ClassLoader
>   (TCCL).
>
> There are a number of issues with the above mechanisms when used in
>   OSGi:
>
> 1. The Thread Context ClassLoader is not defined in general in an OSGi context. It can and has to be set by the caller and OSGi cannot
>      generally enforce that.
> 2. A bundle can't Import-Package META-INF/services as potentially many bundles will contain this pseudo-package and the OSGi framework
>      will only bind a single exporter to an importer for a given package.
> 3. Instantiating an SPI provider generally requires access to internal implementation classes, by exporting these classes an
>      implementing bundle would break its encapsulation.
> 4. Even if an implementation class was exported, importing this class in a consumer bundle would bind it to the specific implementation
>      package provided, which violates the principle of loose coupling.
> 5. Bundles have a dynamic life-cycle which means that provided services could disappear when a bundle is updated or uninstalled. The
>      java.util.ServiceLoader API does not provide a mechanism to inform
>      service consumers of such an event.
>
> The SPI Fly project makes it possible to use existing code that uses
>   ServiceLoader.load() and similar mechanisms under OSGi.

---

***Please note that as of 2016-05-20 new versions of the `com.googlecode.soundlibs` artifacts were uploaded to the maven central repository. These new versions of the artifacts are proper OSGi bundles. This will help everyone who needs to use the Java Sound API within an OSGi container***

I created a [simple example project on github](https://github.com/axiopisty/osgi.mp3spi.integration) that demonstrates how to play an MP3 file inside an OSGi container using the Java Sound API. Checkout the branch `static-weaving` and `dynamic-weaving` to see the respective solutions.